# how to fetch audit log from a azure kubernetes cluster? later i want to use it to define using audit2rbac tool

Tags: azure, kubernetes, audit, azure-aks

Need to define RBAC based on the audit log. This can be a regular process to onboard a team and provide access.

I find audit2rbac tool simple and clear to use.

Need guidance wrt kubernetes service on azure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example query for getting audit logs from Azure Log Analytics.

It removes some of the noise to try and give just logs for when a user has modified a resource in Kubernetes. The requestURI and requestObject fields will give you the most info about what the user was doing.

```
AzureDiagnostics
| where Category == "kube-audit"
| extend log_j=parse_json(log_s) 
| extend requestURI=log_j.requestURI 
| extend verb=log_j.verb 
| extend username=log_j.user.username
| extend requestObject = parse_json(log_j.requestObject)
| where verb !in ("get", "list", "watch", "")
| where username !in ("aksService", "masterclient", "nodeclient")
| where username !startswith "system:serviceaccount:kube-system"
| where requestURI startswith "/api/"
| where requestURI !startswith "/api/v1/nodes/"
| where requestURI !startswith "/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/"
| where requestURI !startswith "/api/v1/namespaces/ingress-basic/"
```

Comment: what is `log_s` ? It's saying "Failed to resolve scalar expression named 'log_s'" when running this exact command.

Answer (score 0):

The control plane log streams (including the audit log) are available through Azure diagnostic logs. See here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/aks/view-master-logs

Comment: which is the best tool for defining rbac for AKS ?